Optimal Transport in vectorized way with minibatches in Python
I am trying to split pairs of large datasets into minibatches to compute minibatch-wise OT plan. This is slow for large datasets since it involves a for loop. The POT library does not seem to support batched operations.
Let's say I have two arrays of shape (128,2) each. If I want to calcuate EMD in minibatches of 32, I would do:
reshaped_arr1 = arr1.reshape(4, 32, 2)
reshaped_arr2 = arr2.reshape(4, 32, 2)

ps = []
for i in range(4):
    a = reshaped_arr1[i]
    b = reshaped_arr2[i]
    M = cdist(a,b)**2
    p = ot.emd(, , M)
    ps.append(p)

For large number of minibatches, this is slow due to the for loop. I am looking for a library or write my own class that can do something like
my_ot.emd(arr1,arr2,minibatchsize=32)

or
my_ot.emd(reshaped_arr1,reshaped_arr2,batched=True)

in a vectorized way.

This seems to be a programming rather than a statistics question, so maybe try stackoverflow instead. As a programming question I don't see how vectorization would speed up the code and I'd recommend parallelizing it instead.

stackoverflow rejected this as "off-topic". I was hoping vectorized operations across an (n, 32, 2) array would be faster than for-looping through n (32,2) batches. I will try a parallelized approach too, thanks.


stackoverflow rejected this as "off-topic". Welp, I upvoted and maybe somebody knows something, but I think you want to solve n optimization problems and that's just computationally expensive.


The other option is to solve one OT optimization problem with 32*n samples, and that is considerably worse. The minibatch approach is intended to avoid that. Some sort of parallelization or vectorization could further speed this up but I cannot figure out how to do that. Thank you for the upvote.
